# Always Fit screen - 100 vh not working on google maps

Tags: css, wordpress, google-maps

Hi guys Im dealing very long time with some problems about 100% of screen height map. My Client installed many plugins and its generating many classes div's and boxes and Im almost giving up with this one. I have white strip in the bottom whenever there is more content or something pushing content down. ( https://powerspot.pl/  <- this is address and this is screenshot -> http://prntscr.com/f1hhjk ). Any ideas how to make map always fit exactly to screen with no white strips or any other problems ?

Comment: The map is 100% of the viewport height. It's your map overlays that are causing the _"white strips."_ They're overflowing the map.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flex box, it's very useful in this cases. check here [link](http://geon.github.io/programming/2016/02/24/flexbox-full-page-web-app-layout)

```
html,
body,
.full-screen {
 height: 100%;
}
/* Parent of the map view */
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
 }
/* Map */
.map {
  flex: 1; /* Will stretch the container */
}
```

Comment: was trying to work with your ideas but still nothing :(